# Passing parameter to neo4j cypher query

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a java program for connecting to neo4j. Wanted to pass parameter which is a variable value given by user to cypher query.

```
    void connect() {

    graphDataService = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    Transaction transaction = graphDataService.beginTx();

    String name = "";

    Scanner sc_name = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter name : ");
    name=sc_name.next();

    try {
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDataService);
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n = node(*) where n.nodename = ? return n");
        System.out.println(result.dumpToString());
        transaction.success();
    }

    finally {
        transaction.finish();
    }
}
```

How should I connect value in variable **name** that will replace **?** and fetch the result. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil;
...
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("START n=node(*) WHERE n.nodename={name}, return n", MapUtil.map("name", "value");
```